# Merge with subquery in Vertica

Tags: vertica

I was trying to insert only distinct records from source table to destination table using `Merge` command in Vertica. I had tried the same thing in `SQL` using subquery but in vertica its not allowing.
following is the error:

```
[Vertica][VJDBC](5665) ERROR: Subquery in MERGE is not supported
```

please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It was not possible to use Subquery in vertica merge.

```
MERGE INTO Target TGT
USING (Select distinct * from Sources) as SRC 
ON TGT.CD = SRC.CD
```

I created a view for :

```
Select distinct * from Sources
```

used it like this:

```
MERGE INTO Target TGT
    USING SRC_VW as SRC 
    ON TGT.CD = SRC.CD
```

it solved the purpose. Just thought of posting it for future use only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to perform a MERGE operation with big data volumes?

Then, you should consider enabling an *optimized MERGE* plan instead of a standard MERGE, which is considerably faster.

Should you be interested, shout, and I'll explain you the details as yet another answer here.

Happy playing

Marco the Sane

Comment: Yes please. That will help others as well. But the above solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized MERGE possibility.

I'm basing it on a mutilated Slowly Changing Dimension table. It brings the idea across, but don't take it as a design blueprint for anything in reality ....!

Let’s say you have, among other rows, these in your target table. cust_key is the surrogate primary key, and the combination of cust_id and cust_to_dt is the other unique identifier of the table:

```
cust_key|cust_id|cust_to_dt|cust_first_name  |cust_last_name    |cust_phoneno      |cust_loyalty_lvl|cust_org_id
       1|      7|9999-12-31|Lionel           |Prosser           |+41(0)79 387 31 07|               1|          0
       2|     14|9999-12-31|Hotblack         |Desiato           |+41(0)79 387 31 14|               2|          0
       3|     21|9999-12-31|Slartibartfast   |Slartibartfast    |+41(0)79 387 31 21|               3|          0
       4|     28|9999-12-31|Pizpot           |Gargravarr        |+41(0)79 387 31 28|               4|          0
       5|     35|9999-12-31|Know-Nothing-Bozo|the Non-Wonder Dog|+41(0)79 387 31 35|               5|          0
       6|     42|9999-12-31|Fook             |Fook              |+41(0)79 387 31 42|               6|          0
```

The definition of the target table would be this:

```
-- create a stand-alone sequence 
CREATE SEQUENCE source_seq;
-- the target's surrogate key defaults to its sequence's NEXTVAL ….
CREATE TABLE target (
  cust_key         BIGINT DEFAULT target_seq.NEXTVAL NOT NULL
, cust_id          BIGINT
, cust_to_dt       DATE
, cust_first_name  NCHAR VARYING(30)
, cust_last_name   NCHAR VARYING(30)
, cust_phoneno     NCHAR VARYING(30)
, cust_loyalty_lvl BIGINT
, cust_org_id      BIGINT
, PRIMARY KEY(cust_key)
)
UNSEGMENTED ALL NODES;
```

Your source table – without the surrogate key value for starters – looks like this. 6 rows are updates of existing ones, and 1 new row, Thor with cust_id 43.:

```
cust_id|cust_to_dt|cust_first_name  |cust_last_name    |cust_phoneno      |cust_loyalty_lvl|cust_org_id
      7|9999-12-31|Lionel           |Prosser           |+41(0)79 387 31 07|               2|          0
     14|9999-12-31|Hotblack         |Desiato           |+41(0)79 387 31 14|               3|          0
     21|9999-12-31|Slartibartfast   |Slartibartfast    |+41(0)79 387 31 21|               4|          0
     28|9999-12-31|Pizpot           |Gargravarr        |+41(0)79 387 31 28|               5|          0
     35|9999-12-31|Know-Nothing-Bozo|the Non-Wonder Dog|+41(0)79 387 31 35|               6|          0
     42|9999-12-31|Fook             |Fook              |+41(0)79 387 31 42|               7|          0
     43|9999-12-31|Thor             |Thor              |+41(0)79 623 84 75|               6|          1
```

Your MERGE source table is built like the target table.:

```
CREATE TABLE merge_src LIKE target INCLUDING PROJECTIONS;
```

You fill it from the delta table so that you pick the existing surrogate keys from the target, and where they don’t exist, you use `target_seq.NEXTVAL` to get a new surrogate key. In order to do that, you left join your source to your target using the the combination of `cust_id` and `cust_to_dt`, the other possibility to uniquely identify the target rows:

```
INSERT /*+ DIRECT */ INTO merge_src
SELECT
  IFNULL(tgt.cust_key,target_seq.NEXTVAL) AS cust_key
, src.cust_id
, src.cust_to_dt
, src.cust_first_name
, src.cust_last_name
, src.cust_phoneno
, src.cust_loyalty_lvl
, src.cust_org_id
FROM source src
LEFT
JOIN target tgt
USING(cust_id,cust_to_dt)
;
```

Your merge source table now looks like this – the new row with cust_id 43, Thor, gets a new surrogate key:

```
SQL>select * from merge_src;
cust_key|cust_id|cust_to_dt|cust_first_name  |cust_last_name    |cust_phoneno      |cust_loyalty_lvl|cust_org_id
       1|      7|9999-12-31|Lionel           |Prosser           |+41(0)79 387 31 07|               2|          0
       2|     14|9999-12-31|Hotblack         |Desiato           |+41(0)79 387 31 14|               3|          0
       3|     21|9999-12-31|Slartibartfast   |Slartibartfast    |+41(0)79 387 31 21|               4|          0
       4|     28|9999-12-31|Pizpot           |Gargravarr        |+41(0)79 387 31 28|               5|          0
       5|     35|9999-12-31|Know-Nothing-Bozo|the Non-Wonder Dog|+41(0)79 387 31 35|               6|          0
       6|     42|9999-12-31|Fook             |Fook              |+41(0)79 387 31 42|               7|          0
250,007|     43|9999-12-31|Thor             |Thor              |+41(0)79 623 84 75|               6|          1
```

The MERGE between merge_src and target uses an optimized MERGE, using the surrogate key in the ON clause (I just replaced the code for the digraph objects for the GraphViz format by [...] placeholders). Look especially at the Access Path for the DELETE – it has a MERGEJOIN (inputs presorted) and uses Side Information Passing (SIP1):

```
SQL>EXPLAIN
...>MERGE /*+DIRECT*/
...>INTO target t
...>USING merge_src s
...> ON s.cust_key         = t.cust_key
...>WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
...>  cust_key         = s.cust_key
...>, cust_id          = s.cust_id
...>, cust_to_dt       = s.cust_to_dt
...>, cust_first_name  = s.cust_first_name
...>, cust_last_name   = s.cust_last_name
...>, cust_phoneno     = s.cust_phoneno
...>, cust_loyalty_lvl = s.cust_loyalty_lvl
...>, cust_org_id      = s.cust_org_id
...>WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
...>  cust_key
...>, cust_id
...>, cust_to_dt
...>, cust_first_name
...>, cust_last_name
...>, cust_phoneno
...>, cust_loyalty_lvl
...>, cust_org_id
...>) VALUES (
...>  s.cust_key
...>, s.cust_id
...>, s.cust_to_dt
...>, s.cust_first_name
...>, s.cust_last_name
...>, s.cust_phoneno
...>, s.cust_loyalty_lvl
...>, s.cust_org_id
...>);
QUERY PLAN
------------------------------
QUERY PLAN DESCRIPTION:
------------------------------

EXPLAIN MERGE /*+DIRECT*/ INTO target t USING merge_src s ON s.cust_key = t.cust_key WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET cust_key = s.cust_key , cust_id = s.cust_id , cust_to_dt = s.cust_to_dt , cust_first_name = s.cust_first_name , cust_last_name = s.cust_last_name , cust_phoneno = s.cust_phoneno , cust_loyalty_lvl = s.cust_loyalty_lvl , cust_org_id = s.cust_org_id WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( cust_key , cust_id , cust_to_dt , cust_first_name , cust_last_name , cust_phoneno , cust_loyalty_lvl , cust_org_id ) VALUES ( s.cust_key , s.cust_id , s.cust_to_dt , s.cust_first_name , s.cust_last_name , s.cust_phoneno , s.cust_loyalty_lvl , s.cust_org_id )

Access Path:
+-DML INSERT [Cost: 0, Rows: 0]
|  Target Projection: scd.target_super
|  Target Prep:
| +---> STORAGE ACCESS for s [Cost: 40, Rows: 7 (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 3)
| |      Projection: scd.merge_src_super
| |      Materialize: s.cust_key, s.cust_id, s.cust_to_dt, s.cust_first_name, s.cust_last_name, s.cust_phoneno, s.cust_loyalty_lvl, s.cust_org_id


[...]

Lock Map - Table (Mode)
----------------------------------------------
target(I)
----------------------------------------------
------------------------------
QUERY PLAN DESCRIPTION:
------------------------------

EXPLAIN MERGE /*+DIRECT*/ INTO target t USING merge_src s ON s.cust_key = t.cust_key WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET cust_key = s.cust_key , cust_id = s.cust_id , cust_to_dt = s.cust_to_dt , cust_first_name = s.cust_first_name , cust_last_name = s.cust_last_name , cust_phoneno = s.cust_phoneno , cust_loyalty_lvl = s.cust_loyalty_lvl , cust_org_id = s.cust_org_id WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( cust_key , cust_id , cust_to_dt , cust_first_name , cust_last_name , cust_phoneno , cust_loyalty_lvl , cust_org_id ) VALUES ( s.cust_key , s.cust_id , s.cust_to_dt , s.cust_first_name , s.cust_last_name , s.cust_phoneno , s.cust_loyalty_lvl , s.cust_org_id )

Access Path:
+-DML DELETE [Cost: 0, Rows: 0]
|  Target Projection: scd.target_super (DELETE ON CONTAINER)
|  Target Prep:
| +---> JOIN MERGEJOIN(inputs presorted) [Semi] [Cost: 11, Rows: 7 (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 1)
| |      Join Cond: (VAL(2) = t.cust_key)
| | +-- Outer -> STORAGE ACCESS for t [Cost: 5, Rows: 6 (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 2)
| | |      Projection: scd.target_super
| | |      Materialize: t.cust_key
| | |      Runtime Filter: (SIP1(MergeJoin): t.cust_key)
| | +-- Inner -> SELECT [Cost: 5, Rows: 7 (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 3)
| | | +---> STORAGE ACCESS for s [Cost: 5, Rows: 7 (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 4)
| | | |      Projection: scd.merge_src_super
| | | |      Materialize: s.cust_key

Lock Map - Table (Mode)
----------------------------------------------
target(X)
----------------------------------------------
```

Hope all this makes some sense…

Happy playing -

Marco the Sane